# How to find the derivative to this equation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can someone please explain the steps to find the derivative of:
$$\dfrac1{2(\sqrt[3]{x^2})}$$
I know the answer is $\dfrac{-1}{3x^{5/3}}$ but I'm confused on how to get there.  Sorry if this was hard to understand, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you know the quotient rule? You could also change them slightly and use the power rule.

Comment: Hint: Your function is $\frac{1}{2}x^{-2/3}$.

Comment: The power rule states that the derivative with respect to $x$ of $x^n$ is $nx^{n - 1}$ for all $n \neq 0$. The quotient rule states that the derivative with respect to $x$ of $f(x)/g(x)$ is $(g(x)f'(x) - f(x)g'(x))/g(x)^2$ whenever $g(x) \neq 0$. The original function $h_1(x) = 1/2x^{2/3}$ can be computed using the quotient rule by letting $f(x) = 1$ and $g(x) = 2x^{2/3}$. Since your function can be written as $h_2(x) = x^{-2/3}/2$, it can also be computed using the product rule by letting $n = -2/3$. Can you see how the the power and quotient rules can be used to compute your derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt[3]{x^2}=x^\frac23$$
$$\dfrac1{2\sqrt[3]{x^2}}=\dfrac12*x^{-\frac23}$$
Using the Power Rule which is:
$$\frac d{dx}\left(ax^n\right)=anx^{n-1}$$
$$\dfrac d{dx}\left(\dfrac12*x^{-\frac23}\right) = \frac12*-\frac23x^{-\frac53}$$
$$=-\frac13x^{-\frac53}$$
$$=-\frac1{3x^{\frac53}}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINTS: (OR RULES)

$$ \frac{1}{a^n} = a^{-n} $$

$$ \frac{d x^n}{dx} = n x^{n-1} \; \; \; \; (proof?) $$

$$ (cf)' = cf' $$

$$ \sqrt[m]{a^n} = a^{\frac{n}{m}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac d{dx}( \dfrac1{2(\sqrt[3]{x^2}})$$

$$\frac d{dx} (\frac{1}{2} *(x^{-2/3 })$$

$$ \frac{1}{2} * \frac{-2}{3}(x^{-2/3 -1})$$

$$ \frac{-1}{3} (x^{-5/3})$$

Answer (score 0):

If it's too complicated, make a substitution to simplify it.

e.g. start with $u = 2 \sqrt[3]{x^2}$. Now the problem is to differentiate $\frac{1}{u}$ (with respect to $x$).